# bluimp with angular, triggering upload manully

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, angularjs-directive

I am using [this tutorial](http://code-like-a-poem.blogspot.co.il/2013/05/angularjs-tutorial-4-file-upload-using.html).
The problem is that the directive returns the upload object, which basically triggers the upload automatically when a file is selected.

I though that some one who has a deeper understanding of AngularJS than I do can think of a way to trigger the upload event of bluimp manually, perhaps by a key press, or within a callback.

Answer (score 1):

Can you look @ below url they are giving file upload with start button:

http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/angularjs.html

Comment: Ok, managed to access the page using FF - weird.

Anyways, from reviewing the code there it appears that that they are using angular.provide to create an API with the jQuery plugin.

I am looking for a lightweight easy solution, preferably using the code that I have already integrated.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where the problem is but this might save you the hassle of figuring out file upload in angular:

You can use the simple/lightweight [angular-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload) directive.
It supports non-HTML5 browsers with FileAPI flash shim. It also supports drag&drop and upload progress.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <input type="file" ng-file-select="onFileSelect($files)" multiple>
</div>
```

JS:

```
//inject angular file upload directive.
angular.module('myApp', ['angularFileUpload']);

var MyCtrl = [ '$scope', '$upload', function($scope, $upload) {
  $scope.onFileSelect = function($files) {
    //$files: an array of files selected, each file has name, size, and type.
    for (var i = 0; i < $files.length; i++) {
      var $file = $files[i];
      $upload.upload({
        url: 'my/upload/url',
        file: $file,
        data: {item: $scope.myModel},
        headers: {...}
        progress: function(e){}
      }).then(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // file is uploaded successfully
        console.log(data);
      }); 
    }
  }
}];
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried working with your uploader and it wasn't good for me.
I opened some issue on your gitHub repo a while ago if you recall.

The main problem is that it uses SWF fallback.

Comment: Also you don't seem to support additional form data and manual triggering of the upload.
Thanks for your response

Comment: You can send additional data with the file, I updated the answer. Version 1.1.1 also allows you to upload the file manually with $upload angular service. I think you were using the first version.

Comment: If you don't use SWF fallback you won't be able to get the upload progress, FormData or actual file binary on the client side for IE9 or older. You won't be able to do client side validation on the file size or type either. So your code will have to send the file as a form submission without any control over it.